# How may I access elements in a session attribute ArrayList<objects> in JSP

Tags: java, session, el

I'm trying to display returned "titles" from an sql database to the front's JSP file.

In my controller I have

```
ArrayList<ItemBean> inventoryArray = inventory.getInventory(10);            
session.setAttribute("inventory", inventoryArray);
```

Item has a variable String title. I get it using ItemBean.getTitle();
I'm trying to display a list of titles from the itemBeans inside ArrayList inventoryArray.  How would I display that list of titles in JSP?

All I have in my jsp is

```
session.getAttribute("inventory");
```

which works fine but i'm confused at how to access the elements and print them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can access ArrayList in session and iterate as below.

```
<%  
// Retrieve the list from the session
ArrayList<ItemBean> list = (ArrayList<ItemBean>) session.getAttribute("inventory");

// Iterate ItemBean list
for(ItemBean itemBean: list) {
    // You can do you logic here.
%>
```

or You can retrieve as object list.

```
<% ArrayList<Object[]> inventoryList= (ArrayList<Object[]>)session.getAttribute("inventory"); %>

//if you want to get the array of inventory list as below:

<% for(Object[] inventoryListObject: inventoryList) {
    System.out.println(inventoryListObject[0]);
} %>
```

Comment: I have to import the item bean for that though, is that considered good practice? does that break the MVC pattern?

Comment: @veral, I updated my answer here. if you don't like to access your bean in JSP, then don't set it to session. you can set to session as ArrayList<String> instead of ArrayList<ItemBean>.

Comment: try this @SuppressWarnings(“unchecked”)
ArrayList<Object[]> inventoryList= (ArrayList<Object[]>)session.getAttribute("inventory");